# Cannot get Webs of SPSite object

Tags: 2010, spweb, spsite, runwithelevatedprivileges

I try to get all webs of an SPSite (via Powershell) on a SharePoint 2010. 
First I tried to get all the webs like this:

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://<url>
$webs = $site.AllWebs
```

Every time tried it i got an invocation exception. The user I used to get the webs is farmadministrator and sitecollectionadministrator.
So I tried to get webs with elevated priviliges:

```
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity]::RunWithElevatedPrivileges({
$site = Get-SPSite http://<url>
$webs = $site.AllWebs
Write-Host "Web count: $($webs.Count)"
})
```

But this just results in an empty output.

Comment: What error message you get?

Comment: $site.AllWebs : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], TargetInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All permissions required to correct this error:

Site Collection administrator on the SPSite (whether given through Central Admin or Site Settings)

PowerShell scripting admin: add-spshelladmin domain\username

PowerShell scripting admin on the content databases: get-spcontentdatabase | add-spshelladmin domain\username

note that the powershell commands must be run by the farm account (or someone else who already has these permissions)

[SPSite.allwebs returns error](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17247/spsite-allwebs-returns-error)